# What natural processes can cause Catastrophic Failure of a Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive

My understanding of conventional hard drives is they fail slowly.  Something breaks and skips along the platters and data begins to be corrupted.  I believe this is what the mean-time-between-failures indicates.

Is there a 'natural' way for a drive to be fully useless?  I know there are systematic way to accomplish this (e.g. EM guns).  Ideally I'd like to see statistics on the chances of a drive experience **complete** failure?

Comment: So you are practically asking what the chances are that a drive fails in a way that none of the data is recoverable, even by government agencies?

Comment: If you have enough money *and* time there's virtually no way that a **properly used** drive's data becomes unrecoverable.

Comment: vladimir: Connor's answer below speaks to the end-user usability of the drive; is there any conceivable way for a properly used drive to not be recoverable?

Comment: kurtovic: The IRS situation is driving me nuts and I'd like some knowledge of the possible causes and nature of drive failure.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Crush and shred the platters with a conical mill, then put the crumbs into a cement kiln at 1400°C. Nobody will get any data out after that (but data could be stolen during the process) http://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: That's not proper use I'd say...

Comment: I'm quite sure there's no way for a drive to die naturally rendering the data unrecoverable.

Comment: @VladimirCravero "That's not proper use I'd say" +1 excellent point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, MTBF is Mean Time **Before** Failure. It's the average time *before* any failure that causes data-corruption at all.

There are lots of things that can cause permanent data corruption, or a damaged drive.

If the controller PCB on a hard drive experiences catastrophic failure, the "drive" as a unit would effectively have "completely" failed, though it's theoretically possible to transplant a controller from a different drive of the same model and possibly recover some of the data.

Alternatively, if you have a read head hit the platter surface, it can become damaged and being scraping the disk surface off the platters. While this isn't "instantaneous", it could happen fast enough that even if you de-power the drive, just the momentum of the disks would be enough to generate sufficient particulate matter that the drive is no longer functional.

Simply dropping a drive when it's running can easily be enough to trigger this kind of failure.

Frankly, *most* mechanical failures for hard drives are going to be somewhat catastrophic, simply because the interior conditions of a hard drive are so delicate. Anything that releases particulate matter into the drive internals will likely cause irrevocable damage, simply because it will get dragged between the heads and the platter, and damage one or both of them.

The fact that modern drives are so amazingly reliable, and often do fail in a predictable (and gradual) manner is really a testament to the amazing design and engineering effort that goes into them.

Comment: These are the types of failure I'm familiar with but they generally result in a degradation of the drive which is almost always recoverable from my limited understanding of drive failure.  Apart from obvious exposure (fire, water, high impact, malicious intent) what common ways make a drive completely unrecoverable?

Comment: Theft. It's hard to recover your data from a drive that's been stolen.  There isn't really anything "catastrophic" that can go wrong besides the already listed problems.  When drives used to be made of glass the platters could explode, but not these days.

Comment: @CoreyAlix - Disk surface damage is not recoverable. Head failures can cause disk surface damage. Also, the impact required to cause such issues is much less then I think you suspect. Most drives are rated for a 10G impact limit when they're actually spinning.

Answer (score 1):

I've put several drives in for data recovery, and there is virtually always a way to get most of the data off, **if** it failed naturally.

Worst case, the drive board or the platters are swapped with another similar drive and even if the heads crashed and damaged an area of the platter, most of the data should be recoverable for a few thousand $$.

Comment: Wow, that's expensive enough to qualify as catastrophic in many cases!  What type of damage occurs at this price level?

Comment: $1.5K-$2k is just for dead electronics or click of death..